# How to version model validations for an API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some thoughts on API versioning:

Why is API versioning necessary at all? It is required for when we want to make some breaking changes to an API endpoint, like stop accepting certain parameters or if we remove some part of the response, which clients, already consuming our API, expect. In that regard it is pretty straight forward how we do this:

```
1.we create a new folder namespace api/v2;
2.we put there the controller, containing the new version of the endpoint api/v2/controllers/locations_controller.rb;
3.we implement our controller action;
4.maybe for the response we use a different active model serializer/jBuilder template.
```

However, what do we do, if we want to change the validation rules for a model? Let's assume, we have a field foo, which in version 1 of the API, accepts three values a, b and c. So in the model we have a validaiton like so:

```
validates :foo, inclusion: { in: %w(a b c) }
```

Now we want to remove one of the values (a) and add a new value (d). If we just change the validaiton in the model to

```
validates :foo, inclusion: { in: %w(b c d) }
```

we'll have at least two problems I can think of:

1. If a client of the old endpoint sends value a for parameter foo they'll get a validation error.
2. If we update another attribute bar of an existing record through the new point, which has value a for foo (set in the past through the old endpoint), then we'll get a validation error, that foo is not included in the list (which will be quite unexpected, as we update bar and don't expect to get any errors for foo, which we don't touch at all).

I am expecting is, Is there any way of adding versioning to active models for mentioning the validation, for example having validates_presense_of :mobile_number only for the second version

So I'd like to hear your thoughts on such problems with API versioning, where you don't just make changes to the request and response structure and content of the endpoint, but also to the underlying model. Thank you.

Comment: You can use Form Object Pattern to version your Api validations. You  can move your validation from model to form class. For more info check https://medium.com/@jaryl/disciplined-rails-form-object-techniques-patterns-part-1-23cfffcaf429

Comment: If it's just one change , then you can add a condition like if params[]b,c,d].present , then skip validation and check it through another method . But yes , the right way to go forward would be to make a v2 folder as the code is more readable and maintainable .

Comment: If this case is only for one model then what i suggest is, use `attr_accessor` like "v1_validation" and `v2_validation`, in controller action i am using you are getting version of api. add `true`  value for that validation and in model add condition for that validation. I hope you understand what i am trying to say

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is a common case for all models as changes can appear in any table and the associated model will be changed.